# spray.can.Http$ConnectionException: Aborted at spray.can.client.HttpHostConnectionSlot.reportDisconnection(HttpHostConnectionSlot.scala:228)

Tags: scala, http, akka-http, spray

I am getting this error when loading huge data via REST call! I am wondering what could be the reasons of this exception. And what could be the solution to fix this.

Comment: Include the code in your question, what are you trying?. By the way, Spray is obsolete

Comment: https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-can/src/main/scala/spray/can/client/HttpHostConnectionSlot.scala

Comment: ` log.warning("{} in response to {} with no retries left, dispatching error...", error.getMessage, format(ctx.request))` (241) I am getting this message